# how to remove an NSMutableArray object by key?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i have structured an NSMutableArray and here is an example

> (
>           {
>           Account = A;
>           Type = Electricity;
>       },
>           {
>           Account = B;
>           Type = Water;
>       },
>           {
>           Account = C;
>           Type = Mobile;
>       } )

when i try to delete Account B using

> [data removeObject:@"B"];

Nothing Happens

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSArray *archivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self dataFilePath]];
if (archivedArray == nil) {
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];           
} else {
    data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:archivedArray];
}
```

Comment: Please provide more insight as to how this array is created, possibly providing some code you're using in your project.

Comment: Of course nothing happens -- there is no @"B" object in your array.  There may be an @"B" object in some object in your array, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using an NSDictionary for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're actually using an array and not a dictionary, you need to search for the item before you can remove it:

```
NSUInteger index = [data indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[(NSDictionary *)obj objectForKey:@"Account"] isEqualToString:@"B"];
}];

if (index != NSNotFound) {
    [data removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error `incompatible block pointer types initializing 'signed char (^)(struct NSDictionary *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)', expected 'BOOL (^)(struct objc_object *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)'`

Comment: Sorry, change the `^(NSDict...` to `^BOOL (NSDict..`

Comment: `incompatible block pointer types initializing 'signed char (^)(struct NSDictionary *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)', expected 'BOOL (^)(struct objc_object *, NSUInteger,  BOOL *)'`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: try a `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
NSArray *accounts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
NSArray *types = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Electricity", @"Water", @"Mobile", nil];

NSMutableDictionary* data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:types forKeys:accounts];
[data removeObjectForKey:@"B"];
```

Comment: Just a simple correction. NSDictionary* data should be NSMutableDictionary so we can call removeObjectForKey

Answer (score -1):

An `NSArray` is like a list of pointers, each pointer points to an object.

If you call:

```
[someArray removeObject:@"B"];
```

You create a new `NSString` object that contains the string "B". The address to this object is different from the `NSString` object in the array. Therefore `NSArray` cannot find it.

You will need to loop through the array and determine where the object is located, then you simply remove it by using `removeObjectAtIndex:`

Comment: This is incorrect. `removeObject:` and similar methods determine object equality by calling `isEqual:`, so the memory address doesn't matter.